# How to get a jQuery plugin wrapper in directive to update AngularJS scope variable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I get the selected date from the jQuery datetimepicker to update the AngularJS scope variable `date1`?

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/3tef6dmr/11

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateCalendarPicker">
    <div class='input-group date datepicker_format' id='datepicker' style="width:{{width}}px">
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>  
</script>


<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div calendar-picker width="200" date="date1"></div>
    <div>The selected date is <b>{{date1}}</b>.</div>
</div>
```

---

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.date1 = '2015-09-19';
})
.directive('calendarPicker', function() {
    var controller = function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
            format:'YYYY-MM-DD',
            defaultDate: new Date($scope.date)
        });   

    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            date : '=',
            width : '@'
        },
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'templateCalendarPicker'
    };
});
```

Comment: I think the only way to do this without a submit button is to set up a broadcast/emit on a rootScope level. but that seems like an overkill. Why not use bootstrap angular date picker. It works like a charm.

Comment: I couldn't find one that has the ability to click on the year and months, and which combines both date and time, as does this datepicker, which is why I am trying to wrap it in a Angular directive so that it does work well in my AngularJS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can listen for `change` event of the picker and update the your model.

```
$(document).on('dp.change', '#datepicker', function (a) {
    var selected_date = moment(a.date._d).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $scope.date = selected_date;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

here you need to use `$scope.$apply();` because this change event is out of angular knowledge, so we need to tell angular to trigger the `$digest` cycle manually to tell the angular to update the scope and the view.

here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u1mjuzaL/),

and to add something more, detach the datepicker when scope is `destroying`

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $('#datepicker').data("DateTimePicker").destroy();
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x9oa0u6n/)

hope this make sense :).

Comment: Yes, this works, but can you explain to me the connection between the JavaScript variable "dp" and the parameter value "dp.change", as when I change the JavaScript variable to dp2222, it still works. http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/w3nbbjm9/

and in your second example, you don't even have the "dp" variable anymore and it works

what is the "dp" referring to then?

Comment: ah nope i just add the `var dp=..` for to test the `change` event.. to do something like `dp.change()..` but it didn't work :), and there is no relationship between them. :)

Comment: ok, but I'm trying to make this directive able to be used multiple times on one page and am trying to figure out why "dp.change" works but not e.g. "dp2.change", what is the "dp" actually referring to?

Comment: I think this is the event they fire when changing the date

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* to use a jQuery date picker? jQuery does not cooperate with AngularJS very well.

There are plenty of AngularJS date pickers that will allow you to access the value through a two-way binding (ng-model) or similar.

Comment: I couldn't find one that has the ability to click on the year and months, and which combines both date and time, as does this datepicker, which is why  I am trying to wrap it in a Angular directive so that it does work well in my AngularJS app.